# How to access a key/value pair with a variable?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I am looking to access a key/value pair dynamically using the a variable. I can get the value I'm looking for using `topics.social.color`, but the topic will change based on the user's selection. How can I dynamically get the topic color using a variable for the topic?

```
let topic = 'social';

const topics = {
    social: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    emotional: {
      color: 'blue'
    },
    physical: {
      color: 'green'
    }
};

console.log(topics.topic.color); // this does not work
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/m-use/pen/XWJKBMB

Comment: Use the brackets notation - `topics[topic].color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
topics[topic].color
```

```js
let topic = 'social';

const topics = {
    social: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    emotional: {
      color: 'blue'
    },
    physical: {
      color: 'green'
    }
};

console.log(topics[topic].color);
```

[Further Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)